# MVC3 How to stop default date and time value being rendered in create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have an implementation of the J-Query UI date picker that i am using on a create view.

When i return a blank form in the get action for the create view the date picker fields are being populated with a default value, 01/01/0001. The fields are declared as nullable in the database.

how can i stop these values from being shown in the view?

This is the get action where i am returning an empty customer site object.

```
public ViewResult Create() 
    {
        CustomerSite customerSite = new CustomerSite();
        var customers = repository.GetCustomers;
        return View(new SiteAdminCreateViewModel(customerSite, customers));       
    }
```

And im using this editor template to remove the time

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

And this is the structure im using in the main view

```
<div class="label-for">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerSite.PremisesStartDate) </div>
    <div class="date-editor">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerSite.PremisesStartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerSite.PremisesStartDate)
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you just check for the value of it? If it's default don't print the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set the default date of the JQuery control?
[Set Jquery Datepicker default date](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)